# InterchangeEditor.uplugin is referenced via project with a mismatched 'SupportedTargetPlatforms' field in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

I am trying to package my Unreal project into APK file using Unreal Engine 5. During packaging, I am getting the below error

```
InterchangeEditor.uplugin is referenced via MyProject.uproject with a mismatched 'SupportedTargetPlatforms' field. This will cause problems in packaged builds, because the .uplugin file will not be staged. Launch the editor to update references from your project file, or update references from other plugins manually.
BuildLogEventException: InterchangeEditor.uplugin is referenced via MyProject.uproject with a mismatched 'SupportedTargetPlatforms' field. This will cause problems in packaged builds, because the .uplugin file will not be staged. Launch the editor to update references from your project file, or update references from other plugins manually.
   at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.AddPlugin(PluginReferenceDescriptor Reference, String ReferenceChain, String[] ExcludeFolders, Dictionary`2 NameToInstance, Dictionary`2 NameToInfos, ILogger Logger) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Configuration/UEBuildTarget.cs:line 4461
   at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.SetupPlugins(ILogger Logger) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Configuration/UEBuildTarget.cs:line 4285
   at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.PreBuildSetup(ILogger Logger) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Configuration/UEBuildTarget.cs:line 3316
   at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.Create(TargetDescriptor Descriptor, Boolean bSkipRulesCompile, Boolean bForceRulesCompile, Boolean bUsePrecompiled, UnrealIntermediateEnvironment IntermediateEnvironment, ILogger Logger) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Configuration/UEBuildTarget.cs:line 1366
   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.CreateMakefileAsync(BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, TargetDescriptor TargetDescriptor, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, ILogger Logger) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Modes/BuildMode.cs:line 1114
   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.BuildAsync(List`1 TargetDescriptors, BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, BuildOptions Options, FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile, ILogger Logger, Boolean bSkipPreBuildTargets) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Modes/BuildMode.cs:line 396
   at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.ExecuteAsync(CommandLineArguments Arguments, ILogger Logger) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Modes/BuildMode.cs:line 252
   at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main(String[] ArgumentsArray) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Saved/CsTools/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.cs:line 659
WriteFileIfChanged() wrote 0 changed files of 0 requested writes.
```

How to resolve it?